Google Analytics 4 Keep Tracking Multiple Domain
I have more than one domain.

DomainC.com - Using Google Tag, GA4, and Google Ads. Installed via Google Tag Manager.
DomainW.com - Same with No 1
DomainK.com - No GTM and GA4. Only installed gtag.js from Google Ads

Problems:

Every DomainK traffic is tracked in GA4 DomainC and DomainW.

Goal:

Make each domain traffic separate from their GA4 account. I don't want their traffic to overlap each other. For example: If a visitor visits DomainW then it's must be only count in DomainW.

What I had tried:

Check if GTM is installed correctly
Check if MEASUREMENT ID is typed correctly
Make sure cross-domain is disabled from Data Stream > Configure tag settings > Configure your domains
Testing using DebugView but what I do with GTM doesn't show.

If you need any additional information. Please comment below.

What exactly do you mean by "Every DomainK traffic is tracked in GA4 DomainC and DomainW". Also, why would you disalbe cross-domain tracking? You seem to be doing random movements without actually debugging the problem. Why don't you look into your network and inspect what requests are being sent to where?

Hi @BNazaruk thank you for your response. I just updated the question. Yes, I tried everything I could that I found on the internet. So, it might be random things. Why do I disable cross-domain? Because I want the traffic separate for each domain.

Cross-domain doesn't mean that the traffic is not "separate". It only synchronizes visitor ids for you to be able to join sessions based on that. I think you're making some simple mistake in how you get to your conclusion that the traffic is overlapping. Show us in the question why exactly you think the traffic overlaps.

I tested it with real-time reports. Every time someone clicks my ads that redirect to DomainK, it shows in DomainC and domains GA4.

Please show screenshots that clearly display that. Plus, show screenshots of the network tab filtered by collect in the landing page after the ad click.

Hi @BNazaruk , thank you for giving clues. Now, I found out the problem. I'll pose the answer soon. Thank you very much.

Special thanks to @BNazaruk who give me some clues.
The main problem is because wrong connection in The Google Tag Manager Container.

On the image above, make sure tag name and tag IDs have the correct GA4 ID. I used GA4 MEASUREMENT ID twice in different Google Tags.
Because, when I check to GA4 > Account > Data collection and modification > Data Streams > Configure tag settings.

To prevent this happen again:
Use clear tag names. Don't just use web stream, blog or whatever that doesn't describe the site. Always use prefix or site word to differentiate.

As per your problem statement, it seems that you have definitely placed the "gtag.js" of some other domain rather than for DomainK.
If your problem is not solved, we can get together on call to solve it. (If you're interested) (PS: I am not charging anything for it.)

No, I'm sure of it. I just checked it. Each domain has a GTM script only. No gtags.js from Google Ads. I appreciate your help. Do I need to contact you directly? Thank you for your response.

Hello, please post only solutions to the question as an answer. If you do not have a solution, please post a comment - even if you do not have sufficient reputation to add a comment, posting a comment as an answer is not appropriate.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
